# Object Relations C#

Tags: c#, class, object, monogame

I'm not sure how best to objectify and access my various game elements. To simplify my issue I've reduced my game classes into fruit:

Say I have a basket of fruit, comprising an orange, apple and banana. Currently the fruitbasket is a single object, though as I now wish to treat the apple as a separate object, what is the preferred way for the apple to access its now broken references to the variables and methods of the basket?

The basket class contains dozens of constant variables which I reference many times within the apple class - as well as various method calls - and I feel it clumsy to call basket.<var/method> every time, nor do I wish to declare new variables within the apple, referencing the dozens of basket values. Although passing variable values is straight-forward enough the same is not true for methods. How would I best reference the basket methods within the apple, as, once again, these methods are demanded many times within the apple. Should the fruit somehow be derived from the basket?

I'm very eager to treat and manage all of my game elements as harmonious objects, working together and facilitating the coding process of a large project. Any help will be appreciated.

I'm using C# and the MonoGame framework within Visual Studio.

Comment: Would you please give your present class construction here?

Comment: In your example, the "Fruit" objects are unrelated to each other, and only share a basket (they only relationship).  I suspect this is not the case in your code, so actually being abstract here does not help us to understand your structure and requirements.  So you need to be more open about what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

---

Derive the apple from the basket
`class Apple : Basket { }`

---

Make every variable/method/etc that you want to access static in the basket. Then, you can simply access it from anywhere. e.g.

```
public class Basket { 
    public static List<string> Content = new List<string>(); 
    public static bool IsEqual(int x, int y) {
        return (x == y);
    }
} 

public class Apple {
    Console.Log(Basket.Content.Count.ToString());
    Console.Log(Basket.IsEqual(1, 2).ToString());
}
```